# group weeks into quarter for a particular year

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There are 52 weeks in a year, If i manually group 13 weeks  into one quarter, it will give me a wrong result in high charts. Sometimes 13th week will be in 2nd quarter,so is there any function which will group weeks into quarter ?

> Iam gettting data in following format:
>   Response is an object,consists of quarterNumber, actual production and planned production and **weekwisedata**, which is a list consists of weeknumber and  weekly planned production and weekly actual production.

```
     {"response":[{"quarterNumber":"1","actualQuarterProduction":"1.5","plannedQuarterProduction":"13.49","weekwisedata":[{"quarterNumber":1,"weekNumber":"1","weeklyPlannedProduction":"0","weeklyActualProduction":"0"},        {"quarterNumber":1,"weekNumber":"2","weeklyPlannedProduction":"13.49","weeklyActualProduction":"0"},       {"quarterNumber":1,"weekNumber":"3","weeklyPlannedProduction":"0","weeklyActualProduction":"0"},
{"quarterNumber":"2","actualQuarterProduction":"211.18","plannedQuarterProduction":"850",
"weekwisedata":[{"quarterNumber":2,"weekNumber":"14","weeklyPlannedProduction":"67.45","weeklyActualProduction":"0"},{"quarterNumber":2,"weekNumber":"15","weeklyPlannedProduction":"67.45","weeklyActualProduction":"0"},{"quarterNumber":2,"weekNumber":"16","weeklyPlannedProduction":"67.45","weeklyActualProduction":"0"},{"quarterNumber":2,"weekNumber":"17","weeklyPlannedProduction":"53.96","weeklActualProduction":"0"},{"quarterNumber":2,"weekNumber":"18","weeklyPlannedProduction":"67.45","weeklyActualProduction":"46.45"}]}
```

> In Highchart iam displayng the data manually as shown below:

```
function(dataVal){
    drilldown: {
            series: [{
                id: 'Quarter1a',
                    name: 'Actual Quality ',
                    data: [{
                        name: 'Week1',
                        y:parseFloat(dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[0].weeklyActualProduction)
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Week2',
                        y:parseFloat(dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[1].weeklyActualProduction)
                    }
                ]
            },
    {
                id: 'Quarter1p',
                name: 'Planned Quantity',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Week1',
                    y:parseFloat(dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[0].weeklyPlannedProduction)
                },
                {
                    name: 'Week2',
                    y:parseFloat(dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[1].weeklyPlannedProduction)
                },
                {
                    name: 'Week3',
                    y:parseFloat(dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[2].weeklyPlannedProduction)
                }
                ]
            } ]

}
```

As you can see the above code,manually iam setting week number and values. iam grouping 13 weeks into quarter. can it be automated based on year?

Comment: But you have in your data `quarterNumber` per every week. Why not iterating over data to generate separate datasets? You mention manual work, could you describe it? For example I can see `name: "Week1"` - why don't you use `name: "Week" + dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[0].weekNumber ` ?

Comment: @Pawel Fus , In backend i am looping first 13 weeks into 1st quarter, and setting those values into a list called weekwisedata[0]. Looping 14th week  to 26th week into 2nd quarter and setting those values into a list weekwisedata[1] and so on.As you can see,in Highcharts drilldown, iam manually setting weekly planned production and weekly actual production over 53 weeks .     For example `Week1:dataVal.response[0].weekwisedata[0].weeklyPlannedProduction.`    In highcharts iam not able to iterate it. could you please describe it?

Comment: Why you can't iterate it? I'm sorry, I'm missing something, probably. Simple `var data = []; for (var i = 0; i < weekwisedata.length; i++) { data.push({ name: 'Week' + i, y: weekwisedata[i].weeklyPlannedProduction })`; This way you can assign this later as `series.data = data`.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel Fus,  but the problem is, I should not consider 13 weeks as 1 quarter for a particular year right? Sometimes, 13th week will comes under 2nd quarter. Is there any inbuilt function, which will group weeks into quarter?

Comment: No, Highcharts require to data be prepared for rendering. You should write a method (or use library) that will group your points the way you want to.